# CMS external upload of files

Tags: java, content-management-system

I am looking for a java based CMS that exposes an API for external file upload.

So for instance I have a Tomcat server with a running CMS. I also have a (standalone) client that needs to add content to the CMS automatically (without user interference).

I already looked into Liferay (using Jackrabbit) but there is no way to upload documents/files from a client.

Does anyone know of a java CMS where this is possible ?

Thanks!
Coenos

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to take time in coding then you could make use of Liferay webservices to create a client yourself. Liferay exposes its core api as web service, using which you can do most of the things. To see the list of services that Liferay exposes check this url 
http://localhost:8080/tunnel-web/axis

Replace localhost:8080 with yours.

To know more about this check out this wiki link

http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Web+services+-+Manage+Users,+Organizations,+User+Groups,+and+Roles+via+SOAP